# In qiskit, doing 2 subsequent measurements of a Hadamard gate on the same qubit always gives 0 on the 2nd one

Tags: qiskit, simulation

When I execute the following circuit, I expect that in both classical registers, the content is identical.

```
q = QuantumRegister(1)
c = ClassicalRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
circuit.h(q[0])
circuit.measure(q[0], c[0])
circuit.measure(q[0], c[1])

backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute(circuit, backend, shots=100)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circuit)

print(counts)
```

And the results are `{'01': 44, '00': 56}`, however I expect `{'11': 44, '00': 56}`

When I run the same circuit in the IBM Quantum Experience with the same simulator, I get the expected results.

What do I miss?

Comment: Which version of Qiskit Terra are you running?

Comment: Qiskit Terra was `qiskit-terra-0.8.2` after running the update, which solved the problem I have `qiskit-terra-0.10.0` now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I run your code on the most recent version of qiskit I get the expected results `{'11': 55, '00': 45}`. It could be the case therefore that you are running an older version of qiskit and this has been fixed recently. I would suggest updating your version using `pip install --upgrade qiskit`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had installed `qiskit-0.11.1` and updated to `qiskit-0.13.0`.